# NoMethodError in ProjectsController#create undefined method `each' for #<String:0x00007fcf9c72e598>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

При отправке формы

```
NoMethodError in ProjectsController#create
undefined method `each' for #<String:0x00007fcf9c72e598>
```

Почему он ругается если `create` есть

Пути

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'projects#index'
  resources :projects
end
```

Контроллер

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
def index
    @projects = Project.all
    @project = Project.new
end

def create
    @project = Project.new(project_params)

    if @project.save?
        redirect_to root_path
    end
end

private 
    def project_params 
        params.require(:project).permit(:title, :todos)
    end
end
```

Индекс

```
<%= provide(:title, 'Main') %>
<% @projects.each do |project| %>
    <h2><%= project.title %></h2>

    <% project.todos.each do |todo| %>
        <ul>
            <li><%= todo.text %></li>
        </ul>
    <% end %>
<% end %>

<%= form_for @project do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :todos %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Ошибка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы хотя бы минимально пытайтесь интерпретировать ошибки. "First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty" явно указывает на форму, у вас есть только `form_for @project`, видимо, `@project == nil`; говорите, это вьюха к экшену `index`? Смотрим контроллер; и действительно, где там `@project`?

Comment: @D-side Проблема в том, что index занимается Project.all и если поставить туда еще и Project.new будет будет осуществляться только последняя строка. Тобишь new. Хотелось бы чтобы создание новых данных занимался action create и делал редайрект на index. Я уже и в форме указал action. Но он все равно ругается

Comment: (1) _"будет осуществляться только последняя строка"_ Што? Почему это? (2) _"Хотелось бы чтобы создание новых данных занимался action create"_ Различайте `new` и `create`. Вы в своём `index` совмещаете то, что в Rails типично делится на `new` (форма создания; **не само создание**) **и** `index` (список). (3) _"Проблема в том, что index занимается Project.all"_ Только в случаях, когда на странице только **список**.

Comment: @karaname, вы путаете - в руби метод всегда возвращает результат выполнения **последней** строки, а вот в создании @переменных вас вообще никто не ограничивает. Их и десяток может быть, когда главная страница отображает кучу разных сущностей, например. У вас на странице есть **форма создания** проекта, и ей надо знать, а кого же она создаёт, для этого и надо определить в index `@project = Project.new`

Comment: @Василиса понял, исправил. Спасибо, но при отправке формы он ругается на строку project = Project.new(project_params) из create action. Пишет undefined method each.

Comment: @karaname, обновите в вопросе код контроллера и вьюхи на актуальный и добавьте полный лог `create` с последующим редиректом на `index`, вместе с ошибкой

Comment: @Василиса изменил

Comment: @karaname, я честно очень хочу вам помочь, но это непросто. **добавьте полный лог сервера для экшна create с последующим редиректом на index, вместе с ошибкой**. Лог у вас в окне терминала, где запущен рельсовый сервер

Comment: @Василиса добавил, ошибка таже

Comment: @Василиса   я решил проблему, вся проблема была в форме :todos все перепутал и изуродовал. Сейчас пофиксил. Спасибо вам за помощь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В форме у вас `<%= f.text_field :todos %>`, то есть вы пытаетесь создать поле todos в проекте. Но у вас `todos` - это ассоциация. Соответственно, чтобы создать проект вместе с тудушками, вам надо:

- добавить в Project `accepts_nested_attributes_for :todos`
- изменить project_params на `params.require(:project).permit(:title, todos_attributes: [:id, :text])`
- изменить форму соответствующим образом
- очень внимательно прочитать про ассоциации в [рельсогайде](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

форма:

```
<%= form_for @project do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %> # что-то мне подсказывает, что он обязателен
    <%= f.fields_for :todos |todo| do%>
      <%= todo.text_field :text %>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: дааа, именно так я и исправил. Догадался, спасибо вам!

Comment: Рада была помочь :) И особенно рада, что вы сами разобрались, @karaname