# Unpermitted parameter: ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

При отправке данных из формы:

```
<%= form_for :project, url: projects_path, html: {id:'form'} do |f| %>

    <%= f.text_field :text, placeholder: 'Новая задача'  %> 

    <%= link_to  'Отмена', '', id:'cancel_link' %>
    <%= link_to  'Отправить', projects_path, id:'submit_link' %>

<% end %>
```

Error:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"OR2HWCi3zVz9gB5VAmnzbEuzIwFGE58JlLrWQdNcws6FVTzqh5Cu0zvUJTUEv2O/sCvU9HuadJYr3mfA40ehGA==", "project"=>{"text"=>"Новая задача"}} Unpermitted parameter: :text
```

Есть две модели

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :todos
  validates :title, presence: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :todos
end

class Todo < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project, required: false
end
```

Модель `Todo` имеет атрибут `text` в котором и должна находиться наша todo

Контроллер

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
def index
    @projects = Project.all
end

def create
    @project = Project.new(project_params)

    if @project.save
        redirect_to root_path
    end
end

def update
end

private 
    def project_params
        params.require(:project).permit(:title, todos_attributes: [:id, :text])
    end
end
```

Картина Project

```
class CreateProjects < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
def change
 create_table :projects do |t|
  t.string :title
  t.string :todos

  t.timestamps
end
```

Картина Todo

```
class CreateTodos < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
def change
 create_table :todos do |t|
  t.text :text
  t.boolean :isCompleted
  t.integer :project_id

  t.timestamps
end
```

Я запрашиваю атрибуты `todo` с помощью `accepts_nested_attributes_for :todos`, контроллер также прописан по гайдам, в `project_params` запрашиваю `todos_attributes`. Но при отправке формы в БД значение `text`. Он не сохраняет.

Comment: Вам срочно что-то нужно делать со внимательностью и умением читать логи и выводы ошибок. Форма у вас для `:project`, поле формы `f.text_field :text`, при это у проекта нет такого поля, есть только title. Само собой, поле text  попадает в неразрешённые. Я ж в прошлом ответе дала вам рабочий вариант формы

Comment: @Василиса я понимаю, что форма для project) Вопрос в этом и заключается, как я могу заполнить text модели Todo. В форме отправляется только title( и это великолепно), но мне также нужно заполнить text. Модель Todo для этого создана, чтобы получить text тудушки отдельно.

Comment: Вы это можете сделать с помощью `fields_for` - посмотрите ещё раз внимательно на форму в моём ответе https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/851069/278796

Comment: @Василиса У меня форма точь в точь как у вас. Я и удивляюсь почему fields_for не работает, а выдает  `Processing by ProjectsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"DlxJxLzj==", "project"=>{"title"=>"a", "todos"=>{"text"=>"b"}}}
Unpermitted parameter: :todos`